# How can I fix my XSLT so that it displays my XML as pictured?

Tags: html, xml, xslt-1.0

I'm new to XML and hoping for a little feedback. I am trying to display my XML so that it looks like this:

[How I hope to get my XML to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUCd1.png)

I can't seem to get the elements to display in the templates. (Clearly, I am not building them correctly). How would I get the title element (Koha) to show up bold and larger as it does in the example? I'm just feeling a bit stuck and my professor is busy and I was hoping someone might be able to offer suggestions about what to do next?

my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<digitalLibrarySystem xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~eom25/657/diglibschema/digitalLibrarySystem.xsd">
<systemMetadata>
<title>Koha</title>
<creator>by Katipo Communications</creator>
<subject>public libraries</subject>
<subject>bibliographic managemen</subject>
<subject>distributed library systems</subject>
<description>Koha was one of the the first open-source Integrated Library Systems. It is used and maintained by the worldwide library community.</description>
<date>2000</date>
<type>ILS</type>
<rights>Open-source</rights>
<identifier xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://http://www.koha.org/">http://www.http://www.koha.org/</identifier>
</systemMetadata>
<aboutRecord>
<recordCreator>Matthew Weidemann</recordCreator>
<creationDate>May 6, 2018</creationDate>
</aboutRecord>
```

My XSLT so far:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <body>
 <h1>"font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h1>
 <h2>by <xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/creator"/></h2>
 <h3><xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/subject"/></h3>
 <br/>
 <p>
 <h4><xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/description"/></h4>
 <br/>
 </p>
  <h5><xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/rights"/></h5>
  <br/>
  <h6><i>Record created by <xsl:value-of 
select="aboutRecord/recordCreator"/> on 
  <xsl:value-of select="aboutRecord/creationDate"/></i></h6>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am confused about the XPaths I think and Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reorganized your XSLT file a little bit.
You would have it a lot easier if you start to correctly indent the files.
And have a look at the differences to begin to comprehend how XSLT works.

So here is your (slightly modified) XSLT-1.0 file which brings you closer to your goal:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- Create HTML header and stuff -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />       <!-- Apply the other templates -->
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Process all systemMetadata sub-nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="systemMetadata">                
        <h1>
            <b><xsl:value-of select="title"/></b>
        </h1>
        <h2>
            <xsl:value-of select="creator"/>
        </h2>
        <h2>
            <xsl:value-of select="subject"/>
        </h2>
        <br/>
        <p>
            <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
            </h3>
        </p>
        <h3>
            <xsl:value-of select="rights"/>
        </h3>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Process all aboutRecord sub-nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="aboutRecord">      
        <h3>
            <i>Record created by <xsl:value-of 
select="recordCreator"/> on <xsl:value-of select="creationDate"/></i>
        </h3>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now you can modify it to *pretty print* the results.
If you want to create the nice border, change the first template to

```
<!-- Create HTML header and stuff -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr><td><xsl:apply-templates /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. You have no idea how much that helped. I am still working on it (it makes me feel stupid), but now I have hope.

Comment: So, if I had the add the template with the border, do I need to then make a table?

Comment: You could add a row `<tr>` and a cell `<td>` and put everything in it, but it does work like it is. BTW you shouldn't add the template, but rather replace the other `<xsl:template match="/">...`.

Comment: I added both tags for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. This actually helps so much and seeing the solution (and all of the things that I left out) will help me as I try and finish my last two assignments.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Is the HTML header responsible for linking the XSLT to the XML? I only ask because I still can't get the stylesheet linked even after I upload both documents.

Comment: This line `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>` in the XML file links the XSLT to the XML. The XSLT should be in the same directory and the name is case-sensitive. And disable NoScript for local files. If not everything is correct, you get a blank page.

Comment: I did change that, but it still says that there's no style associated with it. I don't mean to ask so many questions; I just feel sort of dumb which is frustrating for me as a librarian, but I'll get over it.

Comment: You didn't have to change anything. All I did for testing your code was changing the `href="test.xsl"` to the actual name of my XSLT test file. So this should work. Except for Chrome which sometimes makes diffuse problems. Firefox and IE should be ok.

Comment: I just retested it with your XML above and my answer XSLT and it does work after adjusting the name in the `href`.

Comment: Thanks for verifying it for me. It'll be good for me to try and figure out what I am doing wrong anyway; who knows, maybe I will learn something.